# Oracle extract method returns same output for different rows

Tags: oracle

I need to get the years from the db for multiple records. I tried in this way.

```
CREATE or replace TYPE BODY student_t AS MEMBER FUNCTION getYear RETURN NUMBER IS
yearDOB NUMBER;
BEGIN
    for c in (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.dob) c_year from student s)
    loop
        yearDOB := c.c_year; 
    end loop;
    return yearDOB; 
END;END;/
```

That works without any errors. But it will give the same year for all the different records. How should I fix it? Without using varrays can't we fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by fixing it? . How are you going to read multiple records in a single variable without overwriting?

Comment: Yeah. Got it. So may be I must use varrays here

Comment: Yes. But then it depends on exactly what you need from the function. If you read the list of DOBs , how are you going to use it from the block/application calling this function?

Comment: This function will return the year from the date-of-birth of the last student fetched by the cursor. Because there's no ORDER BY clause on the cursor you can't even predict what row that will be. Perhaps you need to think about supplying a STUDENT_ID or something similar when constructing a STUDENT_T so that the object represents a single student. Best of luck.

Comment: I need to retrieve all the years for all the students dob

Comment: @A.Wen . How are you going to use it? Are you going to generate a report of it or use from a different program / procedure etc? . you can also return the whole cursor as `SYS_REFCURSOR`  type for fetching all records. That is a better approach.

Comment: I just need to call the method and retrieve all the years for all the records

Comment: Then just return a ref cursor

Comment: since this is member method can we use cursors?

Comment: I am new to this area. So can any one tell how to modify above member method to use a cursor?

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times. If you do't get the answer you want immediately **improve your question**. Don't waste the time of the people you're asking to help you.

Comment: Is it me or do you need to use a DISTINCT ? `SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.dob) c_year from student s`

Comment: I tried using distinct but doesn't work